# Eigenvector and eigenvalue of an infinte, symmetrical matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to get eigenvectors and eigenvalue of an infinite matrix like
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&1&0&\dots\\
0&1&0&1&\dots\\
1&0&1&0&\dots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I know, that they should meet the conditions of $Av = \lambda v$, where $A$ is the given matrix, $v$ is an eigenvector and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, but I really don't know, how to compute it on an infinite matrix.

Comment: Is your matrix given by $A_{i,j}=[i\equiv j\pmod2]$ (where the brackets mean $1$ or $0$ as the condition is true or false)? In that case this matrix does not describe a linear operator in any obvious way, and talking about eigenvalues is not really meaningful. If your matrix follows a different pattern, you should be more specific about that pattern.

Comment: Assuming that this question can be asked in a rigorous way, it may help to note that this matrix can be written as 
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&\cdots\\1&1\\ \vdots && \ddots} \otimes \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$